# If the usage of "new" keyword in Java implies memory allocation, why is it not the case for an anonymous inner class?

Tags: java, anonymous-inner-class

As a beginner in Java, I've been taught that the usage of the "new" keyword leads to the invocation of a constructor and thereby memory allocation for the object. If that is indeed the case, what happens when we write:

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
   {
      // do something.
   }
});
```

??

If memory is allocated, is it not violating the concept of "Interfaces cannot be instantiated"? 
Is there no memory allocation for the new ActionListener? If no memory is allocated, how is it accessed when we are not specifying any object reference? 
Or, does this simply act as an exception to the "memory allocation at 'new'" rule??

Comment: It's exactly the same as the rule you were taught - a `new` instance of the anonymous inner class `ActionListener$X` is allocated into memory. Where does your confusion arise?

Comment: The new `ActionListener` is passed in to the `addActionListener` method as a parameter, and inside that method it is likely assigned to some variable inside the `button` object. Memory is indeed allocated for it.

Comment: The fact that you do not assign the object reference created by the "new ActionListener() ..." operation to a local variable does not mean that there is no memory allocation done. An allocation is done and an object reference is created but it is passed directly to addActionListener(...) as a parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case an anonymous(name chosen by the compiler) class is created with a default constructor and implicitly implemented interface of `ActionListener` and happily instantiated like any other class you create with `new` keyword.

Comment: The part that says "name chosen by the compiler" actually answers my question of not having an object reference. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

The new `ActionListener` is most certainly allocated. You define an anonymous class which implements the required methods in the `ActionListener` interface, and since you have defined a concrete class which implements the interface, the compiler is now capable of compiling your anonymous class and instantiating it.

You could just as easily have done:

```
ActionListener al = new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { ... }
};
button.addActionListener(al);
```

It becomes more obvious in the above example that the `ActionListener` has been allocated, because it now has scope outside of the method invocation and can be referred to in subsequent code.

Answer (score 0):

Rather look at the new word as object instantiation.
Is there no memory allocation for the new ActionListener? Yes
If so, how is it accessed? The button object will call ActionListener#actionPerformed() 
passing the action event that has just occurred.

There is no exception to the rule here.